# Rails cannot Create Record with Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code works when I run the action like this,

```
def interest
    @interest = Interest.new
    @interest.user_id = current_user.id
    @interest.idea_id = @idea.id
    @interest.save
    @ideas = Idea.take(10)
    flash[:notice] = "A message has been sent to the poster."
    render "ideas/forum"
end
```

But,why do I get an undefined method for 'interest' when I use this line in my Interest action?

```
@interest = current_user.ideas.interest.create(params[:interest])
```

Here's my Idea model

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    :title
    :category
    :content
    :user_id
    :createdDate
    :updatedDate
```

Here's my User model (Devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ideas
    has_many :interests
end
```

Here is the `button_to` tag

```
<%= button_to "I'm Interested", ideas_interest_path(:id => idea.id, :idea_id => idea.id, :user_id => idea.user_id) ,class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

And my route,

```
resources :ideas do
    resources :interests
end
```

Interest Model 
    class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :idea

has_many :users

:idea_id
  :user_id

end

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `interest' for #<Idea::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f9e5189bab0>:
```

activerecord (4.2.0)

Comment: Add your interest model and error too.

Comment: Add `has_and_belongs_to_many :interests` in your Idea model.

Comment: where is your Interest model? Where did you add?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed Tried it from idea and interest and the relationship did not change the error.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed check again, I think an edit, deleted it prior.

Comment: I think you should use has_many :through, like an user has many ideas through interest.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed One User can have Many Ideas and Many Interests One Idea can have Many Interests from Many Users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72994/discussion-between-sharvy-ahmed-and-snowyetis).

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up the association, I'd do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interests
  has_many :ideas, through: :interests
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :idea

  # user_id, idea_id
end

class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interests
  has_many :users, through: :interests
end
```

Then I guess the rest would work.